# jsonp Unexpected token : (backbone)

Tags: backbone.js, jsonp

I am trying to do api call from my localhost to a different domain (https://xyz)

my solution:

```
<script> // ajax prefilter
    $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.crossDomain ={
     crossDomain: true
    };
    options.xhrFields = {
     withCredentials: true
    };
    options.url = 'https://xyz' + options.url;
});
</script>

<script> // collection
    var KCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/api/s/y/',
    });
</script>

<script> // view
    var DataAgesView = Backbone.View.extend({ 

        render: function(){
            var that = this;
            mycollecion = new KCollection();
            mycollecion.fetch({
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(){
                    console.log('success!');
                },
                error: function() { console.log('Uh Oh!'); },
            }) 
        }
    });
</script>
```

This will send a GET request to "https://xyz/api/s/y"

and I can see the data came back to my browser by looking at the dev tool/network.

But there is this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I am very new to web and backbone.js. I used jsonp to just be able to call cross domains, and I am open to use any other solutions for that (as long as I understand it).

Note that my server returns "json" and I can not change anything from server side.